# Book recommendation about Factor Analysis

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

Hello StackExchange community,
I'd like to study some concepts related to varimax rotation, Average variance extracted, Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin, Bartlett's test, ...

Do you know a book where I can learn about them?

Many thanks

Comment: Probably more suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/.